# Finding row of first value in unsorted list greater than specified number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of dates (sorted descending) and a column of dollars (unsorted) next to them. In Google sheets i'm trying to search the earliest date with an associated dollar amount greater than some value.

This is working for all except one search key and I believe i know why but i'm not sure how to fix it.

This is the formula i'm using

`=XLOOKUP(A38,Data!$B$3:$B,Data!$A$3:$A,,1,-1)`

the purpose is to return the date value (Column A in `Data` is the date) where the dollar amount (Column B in 'Data' is the dollar amount) is greater than cell `A38` in the current sheet. the `missing_value` is left blank, `match_mode` is `1` to return the first dollar amount greater, and `search_mode` is `-1` since the dates are descending i search the associated dollars in reverse order.

This works but maybe only by chance because exactly 1 value fails to return the correct date.

For the value `700` as the search key (replace with cell `A38`), `2021-Nov` is the "correct" return value since its the earliest date with an associated value over the search key (The value being `739`). But when using XLOOKUP it returns `2022-Jul`, and i believe its because that date has the closest value that is greater than `700` even though it's not the first match.

Is there a way to make XLOOKUP (or other matching function) exit early when it's found the something over the key?

Here is the data

```
Date,Total
2023-May,$947
2023-Apr,$929
2023-Mar,$848
2023-Feb,$879
2023-Jan,$779
2022-Dec,$816
2022-Nov,$744
2022-Oct,$719
2022-Sep,$759
2022-Aug,$779
2022-Jul,$713
2022-Jun,$751
2022-May,$760
2022-Apr,$806
2022-Mar,$725
2022-Feb,$787
2022-Jan,$776
2021-Dec,$731
2021-Nov,$740
2021-Oct,$685
2021-Sep,$697
2021-Aug,$658
2021-Jul,$638
2021-Jun,$603
2021-May,$585
2021-Apr,$540
2021-Mar,$516
2021-Feb,$489
2021-Jan,$458
2020-Dec,$429
2020-Nov,$389
2020-Oct,$373
2020-Sep,$368
2020-Aug,$340
2020-Jul,$314
2020-Jun,$302
2020-May,$268
2020-Apr,$224
2020-Mar,$250
2020-Feb,$258
2020-Jan,$256
2019-Dec,$239
2019-Nov,$237
2019-Oct,$222
2019-Sep,$222
2019-Aug,$205
2019-Jul,$200
2019-Jun,$183
2019-May,$184
2019-Apr,$178
2019-Mar,$164
2019-Feb,$156
2019-Jan,$139
2018-Dec,$142
2018-Nov,$131
2018-Oct,$134
2018-Sep,$130
2018-Aug,$123
2018-Jul,$115
2018-Jun,$111
2018-May,$101
2018-Apr,$94
2018-Mar,$89
2018-Feb,$87
2018-Jan,$75
2017-Dec,$69
2017-Nov,$60
2017-Oct,$53
2017-Sep,$48
2017-Aug,$42
2017-Jul,$36
2017-Jun,$30
2017-May,$26
2017-Apr,$21
2017-Mar,$11
2017-Feb,$6
2017-Jan,$2
2016-Dec,$2
2016-Nov,$1
2016-Oct,-$1
2016-Sep,-$2
2016-Aug,-$4
2016-Jul,-$6
2016-Jun,-$7
2016-May,-$8
2016-Apr,-$12
2016-Mar,-$14
2016-Feb,-$15
2016-Jan,-$17
2015-Dec,-$19
2015-Nov,-$20
2015-Oct,-$22
2015-Sep,-$23
2015-Aug,-$27
2015-Jul,-$28
2015-Jun,-$27
2015-May,-$26
2015-Apr,-$25
2015-Mar,-$30
2015-Feb,-$29
```

Comment: if `A38` value is `751` should it return the exact match of `2022-Jun` (since match_mode 1 is for an **exact match or the next value that is greater**) OR  it should be `2022-Jan` for `776`?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work out.

It uses the `MATCH` function

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$3:$A, MATCH(TRUE, Data!$B$3:$B>A38, 0))
```

Comment: it seems MATCH requires the input to be sorted, my dollar amounts are unsorted as they go up and down

Answer (score 0):

After some searching i found an answer i liked

`=index(Data!$A$3:$A,arrayformula(max(if(Data!$B$3:$B>A32,row(Data!$A$3:$A)-row(Data!$A$3)+1))),1)`

This finds the maximal row where the dollar amount is greater than some cell (in this example `A32`) and returns the row number. Then uses index to get the date that is in the associated row.

Can also be changed to `>=A32` for greater or equal to but i'm finding that this actually causes the first returned cell to be blank... not sure if its a bug, but for my purposes using only `greater than` works.